# Page Responsive in iPhone & some mobile, only take around 70% of the width

Tags: php, ios, css, iphone, wordpress

I hope anyone who has a iPhone 5/5S/6/6Plus or any iPhone to help troubleshoot this problem, because when using any Mobile Web tester like mobiletest.me, the problem didn't shows, it only occurs when you browse it in the Real phone. That's why I can't really troublehoot without having a physical iPhone with me.

Example page:
http://xpresszoom.com/u-stay-guest-house-u-express-guest-room-2/

As you can see from the attached image (uploaded from Xiaomi Redmi Note 4g), the page didn't take up the full width as it should be.

The middle part where all the yellow fields are will take up full width but only the header and from the Google map onwards are displaying weirdly.

Anyone can help?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add media query css on your style.css with your device width and height .

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 580px) {
/* Add Styles Css here */
}
```